# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "abastecer" y "suministrar"? ¿Cuál debe usarse para traducir "The glaciers that supply Lima"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

Busco una buena traducción del verbo "to supply", tal como en la frase

> The glaciers that supply Lima with water are melting.

Las dos traducciones que tengo presente son "abastecer" y "suministrar" pero no me queda claro las diferencias entre las dos. Quizás ambos sirven de igual en este caso.

En cualquier caso, ¿cuándo se utilizaría abastecer en vez de suministrar? ¿Cuándo se encuentran los dos verbos sinónimos? ¿Le queda uno de los dos mejor en el caso de la frase anterior?

Comment: También *alimenta*.  Los glaciares *alimentan* las reservas de agua potable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En principio *[abastecer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=03damMg)* y *[suministrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YhZ89rx)* son sinónimos en este sentido, es decir que estrictamente tanto uno como el otro son correctos. Sin embargo, en otro contexto las mismas raíces verbales representan extremos complementarios de una relación. *Abastecer* puede usarse como pronominal (*abastecerse*) con sentido reflexivo, mientras que *suministrar* no.

> *Los glaciares de las montañas abastecen de agua a Lima.*
>   *Lima se abastece de agua gracias a los glaciares de las montañas.*

Quizá debido a esto me resulta a mí más natural el uso de *abastecer* en este caso, ya que estoy pensando en *el abastecimiento que la ciudad de Lima hace, para su propio beneficio, aprovechando el agua de los glaciares*, mientras que cuando pienso en *suministrar*, la imagen que me viene a la mente es la de un agente activamente suministrando algo a otro, cosa que no se corresponde con este ejemplo.

En cambio sí usaría *suministrar* para la acción de proveer o abastecer de agua a los habitantes de la ciudad, que es una acción que realizan el estado y/o las empresas encargadas de tomar el agua, canalizarla, acumularla, potabilizarla y enviarla a los hogares por las cañerías. En mi dialecto, al menos, siempre se habla de esto como de *suministro de agua* (como se habla del *suministro de energía eléctrica*).

El *abastecimiento de agua*, por otro lado, no refiere a la provisión de agua sino a las acciones destinadas a obtener esa agua. Si me dicen que "en Lima está en peligro el abastecimiento de agua", yo interpretaré que la ciudad corre peligro de quedarse sin el agua que necesita para sus habitantes. Si en cambio me dicen que "en Lima está en peligro el suministro de agua", pensaré inmediatamente en que hay un problema con las cañerías.

**No sé si esta connotación es la misma para otras personas.** Como dije, los dos verbos son sinónimos (dejando de lado el pronominal *abastecerse*) y no es un error usar uno en lugar del otro en este caso.

Comment: De acuerdo para España sobre el uso de suministro para la provisión doméstica.

Comment: Aunque los significados son muy parecidos, los regímenes de uso son distintos. Así, en *abastecer* el CD es quien recibe los bienes, que son un complemento introducido por la preposición *de*; en *suministrar^, en cambio, el CD son los propios bienes y quien los recibe es CI. De este modo, aun siendo ambos verbos transitivos, *abastecer* se puede usar sin especificar los bienes, sobre todo cuando es pronominal (podemos decir que *la población se abastece en el mercado central*, por ejemplo).

Comment: Aparte, para mí *abastecer* tiene una connotación de suficiencia de la que carece *suministrar*, tal vez por la similitud de *abastecer* con *bastante* (aunque etimológicamente no tienen nada que ver). Si digo que *mi empresa me abastece de alimentos*, esta frase da una idea de que me da todos los alimentos que necesito, cosa que no ocurre si digo que *mi empresa me suministra alimentos*. Aunque no estoy seguro de que esta connotación sea general o solo cosa mía.

Answer (score 2):

La [respuesta de pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20952/13628) es perfecta. Yo solo quiero darle otro enfoque.

Semánticamente, tenemos que:

- "**Abastecer**", aunque su origen etimológico está en "bastir" (ver comentarios), su significado se identifica con el de "bastar", "bastante", etc. Quiere decir "**hacer que algo baste**", o sea: asegurar que algo esté disponible en cantidad suficiente. Lo que se haga después con ese algo, es otro asunto.

  - En este sentido, los glaciares aseguran que haya bastante agua.
- "**Suministrar**" comparte raíz con "ministro", "administrar", etc.,  que vienen todos del latín *minister*: "sirviente". El verbo quiere decir "**dar el sirviente algo**", dar un servicio.

  - En este sentido, estrictamente hablando, los glaciares no dan un servicio a nadie: son glaciares. Es la Administración (como su nombre indica) la que se encarga de coger el agua que proporcionan los glaciares y servirla a la ciudad.

Nótese que el primer verbo es ligeramente más pasivo que el segundo.

Entonces, siendo estrictos, creo que sería más correcto usar "abastecer" que "suministrar".

Por supuesto, es totalmente válido decir que los glaciares "suministran" agua a la ciudad. Sería una manera de sustituir el todo por la parte (incluyendo el abastecimiento como parte de la cadena de suministro), o de personalizar los glaciares como agentes activos del suministro. Y la diferencia de significado es mínima.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración etimología! Eso apoya mucho mi entendimiento del tema.

Comment: Vaya, he leído esta respuesta después de comentar en la respuesta de @pablodf76. Para mí, la connotación que sugieres para *abastecer* existe, pero no es cierto que comparta raíz con *bastar*; es simple coincidencia fonética. *Abastecer* procede de la raíz germánica *bastjan*, mientras que *bastar* procede del griego *bastázein*.

Comment: @Gorpik ¿_Bastjan_? ¿Como el protagonista de _La historia interminable_, que también es alemana? :-D (Lo siento, no he podido evitarlo.)

Comment: ¡Habría asegurado que las palabras estaban emparentadas! En fin: muchas veces el oído popular crea relaciones semánticas donde no hay relación etimológica previa, y aquí no sería extraño que ocurriese. Al respecto pensemos en lo que revela quizá [esta confusión ortográfica](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/dar-abasto-no-dar-a-basto-799/).

Comment: @walen Por un lado, es posible que los filólogos de la RAE no estén en lo cierto con la etimología de estas palabras; por otro, lo que mencionas sobre la influencia de una palabra en otra es bastante habitual. Hay palabras con significados relacionados que acaban pareciéndose cada vez más porque los hablantes las asimilan.

Comment: Creo que puedes corregir ligeramente la respuesta para aclarar algo más eso de la "raíz" y queda un aporte bastante interesante (por mi parte, ya le puse +1 ayer).

Answer (score 0):

*Suministrar* se usa mas cuando una persona ejecuta la acción.

*Abastecer* se puede usar siempre.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser significativamente distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a la respuesta aceptada. Dale al [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.